# Change back button text in sencha touch detail card of nested list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can I change back button text in sencha touch detail card of nested list.

What I have done in `detailcard` config is :

```
detailCard: {
    xtype: 'panel',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: true,
    html: '  Loading ...... ',
    id: 'detailcard',
}
```

Comment: Where are you changing it? In a controller method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the backText you need to set the [useTitleAsBackText](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-cfg-useTitleAsBackText) attribute to false:

```
useTitleAsBackText: false,
backText: 'Go Back!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [backButton](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-cfg-backButton) configuration of NestedList to customize the text.

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'nestedlist',
    backButton: {
        text: 'Terug'
    },

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`backText`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList-cfg-backText) config for `Ext.dataview.NestedList`:

```
backText: 'Go Back!'
```

[Check it out here.](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ECuRQ)

Comment: It is not showing 'Go Back'. It is showing Groceries. Drinks etc